# Excel Copy Paste 2 rows but only move one row

Tags: excel

Below is a picture of the set up I am trying to get.

[image: a1]

CA**2** is shown below and gets data from Column AX Row **2**.

[image: a2]

CA**3** is shown below and gets data from Column AB Row **2** as well..

[image: a3]

When I copy and paste the above cells they give me row 4, since I am skipping 2 rows that makes sense. What I would like to do is return 1 row back moving down the rows. So instead of copy/pasting and going to AX4, would like to keep the formula, copy both cells and return AX3 for both copied rows.. and so on down the sheet.
Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your problem right, you could try something like this :

[image]

[image]

`=INDEX($E$2:$E$12,ROW()/2)`

`=INDEX($F$2:$F$12,ROW()/2)`

Comment: Can't tell you how much time that saved me! thank you!